# Do all apps have a demo/trial version?

Tags: applications, paid-apps

Someone suggested a pay-for app in another question and when I looked it up, it seemed it didn't have any trial version that has the feature for which I'd pay.

Now, I will not pay for something I have never seen working, even if it's only 4€ and so I was wondering whether I missed something or whether it's usual for pay-for apps to charge before you even can try it?

(This app, Moon+ Reader, does have a free version, but I'm specifically interested in a feature of the pay-for version, so the limited free version doesn't help.)

It seems like a very long time (maybe never) that I payed for any software on my desktop where there wasn't a demo of some sort to try out the key features you payed for.

Comment: Not all apps have a trial version. The developers can decide if they won't to release one or not. I don't see a real question here.

Comment: You can purchase an app, use it and if you aren't satisfied, you can tap Refund button within 15 minutes..

Comment: @Sachin - There's a Refund Button? Cool, I guess that means really every app essentially has a trial version. (Even if only a 10min trial)! Put it as an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Comment: @SachinShekhar If that button is present and can be used with all apps, technically as Martin mentioned, any app has at least a 15min trial period. This is good, consider making your comment an answer.

Comment: @Martin and concerning Moon+: It's worth every cent, excellent support. Even if something doesn't work, just write the author. I'm using this App (Pro-Version) for about 2 years now. But before you ask: No, I don't use PDF files, so I cannot judge this feature; but I know how long Seany looked for the perfect implementation before putting it into action, so it must be good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get 15 minutes trial of all paid apps listed in Play Store. Its Google's policy to refund money if you aren't satisfied but you'll have to claim refund within 15 minutes. After purchasing an app, just look for `Refund` button on app page in Play Store app.

Answer (score 2):

No, not all apps have demo or trail versions. Though [Amazon's Android app store](http://www.amazon.com/b/?node=3071729011&ref=sv_mas_3) has an on-line emulator that lets you try out thousands of different apps in your browser before purchasing.

[image: test-drive]

[image: example-app]